# How to split sentence at sentence boundaries using iterators in python

Tags: python, string, split, iterator

Hi I have to parse a string such that I split it at the punctuation and write each sentence on a separate line. There are some cases where the punctuation is not a sentence boundary and therefore I don't split it there (for debugging purposes I print out a message when these cases occur).

The following is my code (below):

- line is my string that I am reading in
- punctuation list is a predefined list (not that important)
- sentence_boundary is the Boolean that I am trying to use to know when to split the sentence
- I use *i*, *prev* and *c* to check the *current*, *next* and *next,next* characters

Since I worked backwards, the code finds all the conditions that are **NOT** sentence boundaries. It checks for multiple cases and uses iterators to check the next characters. Because I am using iterators, I decided to use recursion to pass in a smaller string everytime so I could iteratively search the whole string. The functionality is working.

However, the goal is to split the string at the points where the punctuation **IS** actually a sentence boundary (i.e. when the other cases are not met). Because of my recursive function I've gotten myself into a bit of a problem where I can't keep track of the index of the list that I am at and therefore don't know where to split the sentence. I was thinking of using a helper function somehow but I don't know how to keep track of the index.

Any help would be appreciated in helping me to modify this code. I know my approach is a bit backwards (rather than looking for where to split the sentence I am looking for where not to split it), but I would like to still work off of this code if possible.

```
def parse(line): #function

sentence_boundary = True

if (len(line) == 3):
    return

t = iter(line)
i = next(t)
prev = next(t)
c = next(t)

# periods followed by a digit with no intervening whitespace are not sentence boundaries
if i == "." and (prev.isdigit()):
    print("This is a digit")
    sentence_boundary = False

# periods followed by certain kinds of punctuation are probably not sentence boundaries
for j in punctuation_list:
    if i == "." and (prev == j):
        print("Found a punctuation")
        sentence_boundary = False


# periods followed by a whitespace followed by a lower case letter are not sentence boundaries
if (i == "." and prev == " " and c.islower()):
    print("This is a lower letter")
    sentence_boundary = False

# periods internal to a sequence of letters with no adjacent whitespace are not sentence boundaries
if i == '.' and prev.islower() and c.islower():
    print("This is a period within a sentence")
    sentence_boundary = False

# periods followed by a whitespace and then an uppercase letter, but preceded by any of a short list of titles are not sentence boundaries
if c == '.' and prev.islower() and i.isupper():
    print("This is a title")
    sentence_boundary = False

index = line.index(i)

parse(line[index+1:])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is quite hard to follow. `prev` is usually short for "previous", so using it with the meaning of "next" makes no sense to me.

The usual approach to keeping extra state like your index between recursive calls is to pass it as an extra parameter. You can start off the first call using the default value of `0`

```
def parse(line, index=0): #function
    ...
    parse(line, index+1)
```